# Item is not accepted while trying to send contacts by bluetooth

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

I am trying to send contacts from SonyEriccson mobile to Windows 8 by Bluetooth. Mobile phone starts transferring, for a moment filename (can't catch it) appears, and then the message says "Item is not accepted by device".

How to make windows to accept all possible items?